# Trying to find leak of type NSMutableArray. Instruments shows leak in method.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, autorelease

I eliminated all the leaks from my current app. However Instruments constantly tells me that I have a leak in the method shown below.

The leak is of type `NSMutableArray` and has a size of either 16 or 32 bytes. Yes, I know that's not much but it adds up. Also see it as an academic question that I need to solve to make my code leakless.

```
+ (id) meterFromDict:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    Meter* resMeter = [[Meter alloc] initWithType:[[dict objectForKey:@"MeterBase"] intValue]];
    //NSLog(@"dict: %@",dict);
    resMeter.volume = nil;
    resMeter.sounds = nil;
    resMeter.repeats = nil;

    resMeter.volume = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"volumeArray"]] autorelease];
    resMeter.sounds = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"soundsArray"]] autorelease];
    resMeter.repeats = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"repeatsArray"]] autorelease];
    //NSLog(@"MeterFromDict called and resmeter.repeats count is : %i",[resMeter.repeats count]);
    resMeter.bpm = [[dict objectForKey:@"BPM"] floatValue];

    return [resMeter autorelease];
}
```

Comment: There is no obvious leak in the code.  It might be in the Meter class?

Comment: You might want to dig deeper and look in the `initWithType` instance method. Maybe there's a leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your Instruments output directly I can't tell exactly, but you're writing some redundant code: Try this:

```
+ (id) meterFromDict:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    Meter* resMeter = [[Meter alloc] initWithType:[[dict objectForKey:@"MeterBase"] intValue]];
    //NSLog(@"dict: %@",dict);

    resMeter.volume = [dict objectForKey:@"volumeArray"];
    resMeter.sounds = [dict objectForKey:@"soundsArray"];
    resMeter.repeats = [dict objectForKey:@"repeatsArray"];
    //NSLog(@"MeterFromDict called and resmeter.repeats count is : %i",[resMeter.repeats count]);
    resMeter.bpm = [[dict objectForKey:@"BPM"] floatValue];

    return [resMeter autorelease];
}
```

There's no point in nilling your properties before assigning new values to them.

Also, No point creating new arrays for arrays that you already have. And if you have properly declared your `volume`, `sounds` and `repeats` properties with `copy` instead of `retain`.

Try that and see if it works better.

Comment: thanks, that actually solved it. Again your code is shorter and more direct, I think I was overthinking when designing that method...